# getting object not found error in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(usl)

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("CSV Viewer"),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
              accept=c('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain','.csv')),
    tags$hr(),
    checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
    fluidRow(
      column(6,radioButtons("xaxisGrp","X-Axis:", c("1"="1","2"="2"))),
      column(6,checkboxGroupInput("yaxisGrp","Y-axis:", c("1"="1","2"="2")))
    ),
    radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                 c(Comma=',', Semicolon=';',Tab='\t'), ','),
    radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                 c(None='','Double Quote'='"','Single Quote'="'"),'"'),
    uiOutput("choose_columns")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Data", tableOutput('contents')),
      tabPanel("Plot",plotOutput("plot")),
      tabPanel("Summary",uiOutput("summary"))

    )
  )
)


####server

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  dsnames <- c()
  u<-
  data_set <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    data(specsdm91)
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(specsdm91)

    data_set<-read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, 
                       sep=input$sep, quote=input$quote)
  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({data_set()})

  observe({
    dsnames <- names(data_set())
    cb_options <- list()
    cb_options[ dsnames] <- dsnames
    updateRadioButtons(session, "xaxisGrp",
                       label = "X-Axis",
                       choices = cb_options,
                       selected = "")
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "yaxisGrp",
                             label = "Y-Axis",
                             choices = cb_options,
                             selected = "")
  })
  output$choose_dataset <- renderUI({
    selectInput("dataset", "Data set", as.list(data_sets))
  })

  usl.model <- reactive({

      df <- data_set()
     # print(df)
      df2 <- df[,c(input$xaxisGrp, input$yaxisGrp)]

      #gp <- NULL
      if (!is.null(df)){

        xv <- input$xaxisGrp
        yv <- input$yaxisGrp
        print(xv)
        print(yv)
        if (!is.null(xv) & !is.null(yv)){

          if (sum(xv %in% names(df))>0){ # supress error when changing files

            usl.model <- usl(as.formula(paste(yv, '~', xv)), data = df)
           return(usl.model())

          }
        }
      }
      #return(gp)
    }
  )


  ##plot
  output$plot = renderPlot({

   plot(usl.model())

  } )

  ##
 # output$summary <- renderUI({

  #  summary(usl.model())

  #}) 

  ##

  output$choose_columns <- renderUI({

    if(is.null(input$dataset))
      return()
    colnames <- names(contents)
    checkboxGroupInput("columns", "Choose columns", 
                       choices  = colnames,
                       selected = colnames)
  }) 
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As you can see I have the df printed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: Please give a reproducible example of your data. Without that, it's hard to imagine what the data types are. In general, I think you have potentially two problems:

1. What is `gp`? You need to return not `gp` but `usl.model`
2. Your `renderUI` is not passing a UI object (i.e. not something the output function will know what to do with).

---

Your problem is that `usl.model` is not actually being saved anywhere, because it's being called within `renderPlot`, which returns only the plot. Since you want `usl.model` to be consumed by two functions, you should take one of the following approaches.

#### Approach 1:

**Define a reactive function** for `usl.model` and reference it in your two output functions.

```
usl.model <- reactive({
    # some calculations probably ending in
    usl.model <- usl(as.formula(paste(yv, '~', xv)), data = df)
    usl.model
})
```

This allows you to reference your model output as `usl.model()` (*the parenthesis are important!*), e.g.

```
output$plot <- renderPlot( plot(usl.model(), add=TRUE) )
```

#### Approach 2

**Create a reactiveValues() variable** to store your `usl.model` as calculated in the plot function.

```
usl.model <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)

output$plot = renderPlot({
    # some calculations probably ending in
    usl.model$data <- usl(as.formula(paste(yv, '~', xv)), data = df)
})
```

You can then refer to your model output anywhere as `usl.model$data`

Approach two is possibly worse because it requires the plot function to be run first.

Comment: I have done your recommendations, still having issues. I've updated the original post with the function and the errors.

Comment: Please give a reproducible example. Without that, it's hard to imagine what the data types are. In general, I think you have potentially two problems:
1. What is `gp`? You need to return not `gp` but `usl.model`
2. Your `renderUI` is not passing a UI object (i.e. not something the output function will know what to do with).

Comment: I just update the whole code. Now I am returning usl.model, getting: Warning: Error in : evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
No stack trace available

Comment: You have induced recursion by referring to the _function_ `usl.model()` within the definition of the function itself! However, your object is stored in the variable `usl.model` without parenthesis. Please remove the parenthesis. But have you considered what gets returned if the code doesn't make it inside the `if` statments?

Comment: I think I got it. is there a way to nicely print the summary of the model?

Comment: maybe `renderText` or `renderPrint`

Comment: when I run this app, the browser screen is showing half. How could I make it so that this app covers the whole browser?